# .NET Core web page refreshing as expected with meta "Refresh" tag but wish to isolate some javascript to not refresh

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating a page using .NET Core that needs to reload every 1-5 seconds and using the meta http="Refresh" tag as below, which is working no problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1" />
```

However, I would like to isolate some javscript code (a prompt to ask a user for permission to use their geolocation) as below:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
// Show a map centered at latitude / longitude.
});
```

(sat in the site.js file). Is there any way from isolating this code from the refresh so that the geolocation is only requested once on the page's initial load?

Thanks very much and hope this is clear!

Comment: Why refresh the entire page? If you'd use `setTimeout` / `setInterval`, you would not have this problem and your page would probably look and behave better. Refreshing the whole page is like being stuck in 2010...

Comment: My problem here is that I also want to use the DateTime.Now value from the system (using C# to generate this value then passing it to the front end). If I am accessing a system value like that every 1 to 5 seconds am I not required to do a full page refresh? This then requires that the geolocation pop up appears again and wipes the permission the user has entered.

Comment: get server time from the system every 1 to 5 seconds, then you might have long-time running connection maybe websocket so that you can ask your server to push system time every 1 to 5 seconds. if you want to keep establishing http connect with the server but just not want to have the popup, I'm afraid you might define a global variable to store the geolocation, and before triggering the popup, just checking this variable.

Comment: If it's OK to refresh a whole page every 1-5 seconds then it could also be OK to fetch data from a simple API endpoint with that frequency. But the approach of Tiny Wang would be better: no connection attempt & handshake every time. However it can be a bit more challenging to build, then again there are great libraries for that, e.g. SignalR which has C# and javascript variations that can talk to each other, all you have to do is set up the connection, create a timer in C# that sends messages as frequent as you want them, and create an event handler for incoming messages on the JS side.

Answer (score 0):

-> modify your code :-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(permissionStatus => {
        if (permissionStatus.state === 'granted') {
            // Geolocation permission already granted, proceed to get current position
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
              
            });
        } else {
            // Geolocation permission not granted, prompt the user for permission
            navigator.geolocation.requestPermission().then(permissionResult => {
                if (permissionResult === 'granted') {
                
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
                  
                    });
                } else {
                    // Geolocation permission denied by the user
                    console.log('Geolocation permission denied.');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error requesting geolocation permission:', error);
            });
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error querying geolocation permission:', error);
    });
});
```